# Use method return value as default constructor parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

This is what I would like to do:

```
object foo {
    def bar = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
}
class foo (baz = bar) {
}
```

This causes compiler errors. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
object foo {
    def bar = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
}

class foo (baz: Array[Int] = foo.bar) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write a secondary constructor:

```
object foo {
    def bar = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
}

class foo (baz : Array[Int]) {
    def this(){
        this(bar)
    }
}
```

Written without IDE or compiler, so someone has to fix the typos.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an auxiliary constructor

```
object Foo {
  def bar = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
}

class Foo(baz: Array[Int]) {
  def this() = this(Foo.bar)
}
```