# Scala: How to define the default value for a constructor parameter within the companion object?

Tags: scala, constructor

The following Scala code does not compile in the Scala REPL 2.11.6:

```
object Foo {
  val DefaultSize: Int = 10
}

class Foo(size: Int = Foo.DefaultSize)
```

The compile error is:

```
value DefaultSize is not a member of object Foo
class Foo(size: Int = Foo.DefaultSize)
```

Tested with Scala 2.11. This is particularly strange, since it follows exactly the accepted answer (in year 2012) here: [Use method return value as default constructor parameter in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234471/use-method-return-value-as-default-constructor-parameter-in-scala), which nowadays does not compile, neither. So how to achieve the intended behavior?

Comment: I just ran this in the REPL (2.11.8) and it compiles properly.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce you error too. Try rebuild your entire project.

Comment: I am running this in the Scala-REPL 2.11.6 on Java 1.8.0_111. Probably something that was fixed in a later version? I will try it with 2.11.8 tonight...

Comment: Ah, in REPL, you need to define both object and class together, in `:paste` mode (or name class differently than the object) ... although I can't explain why.

Comment: @Dima Thanks for the hint with the `:paste` mode. That solves this issue. By the way, the same problem arises with 2.11.11 REPL and 2.12.2 REPL if executed without `:paste` mode.

Comment: The _REPL_ is unable to identify the companion object for a class unless `:paste` mode is used. Refer to the [official documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html) for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [explained in Programming in Scala](https://books.google.ch/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&lpg=PA136&hl=de&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q=%22new%20nested%20scope%20for%20each%20new%20statement%20you%20type%20in%22&f=false), this is because the Scala REPL creates a new nested scope for each new statement you type in.  This implies your code is interpreted as:

```
object Foo {
  val DefaultSize: Int = 10
}
{
  class Foo(size: Int = Foo.DefaultSize)
}
```

While [the same book mentions](https://books.google.ch/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q=companion%20object&f=false) that both the class and its companion object must be defined in the same source file, it seems that they furthermore must be in the same scope, since the code block above [does not compile with `scalac`](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7GHsolpmSCWk7h9x4Aig5Q).

I know two ways to work around this in the REPL.  As mentioned by others, you could enter `:paste` mode before defining the class and companion object.  Alternatively, you could put both into the same scope, e.g., by defining them inside an object:

```
object My {
   object Foo {
     val DefaultSize: Int = 10
   }
   case class Foo(size: Int = Foo.DefaultSize)
}
```

Now you can use `Foo` as expected:

```
scala> new My.Foo()
res0: My.Foo = Foo(10)
scala> new My.Foo(20)
res1: My.Foo = Foo(20)
```

(I made `class Foo` a `case class` to get concise REPL results in the last code block.  The answer works without this change, however.)

Comment: `case class` with `val` is redundant. Case class constructor arguments are already `val`s. It's the case class `toString` method that you are wisely exploiting.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for pointing this out, I had forgotten about it.  I have updated the answer.